# Mongoose cant seem to aggregate a sum and return all the items

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this mongoose query that im running

```
    db.accounts.aggregate([{
        $unwind: "$Publishers"
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: "$Profile._id",
            reachTotal: {
                $sum: "$Publishers.reach"
            },
            Publishers: {
                $push: "$Publishers"
            },
            Profile: {
                $first: "$Profile"
            }
        }
    }, {
        $sort: {
            reachTotal: 1
        }
    }])
```

It works fine, but the problem is that some of the records dont have '$Publishers.reach'. Mongoose doesn't return those records with the sum of null, undefined or 0. Is there a way to have mongoose return them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to tell mongodb what to do in the form of a cond statement or the ifNull statement depending on your document structure.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/

```
...
reachTotal: { $sum: { $ifNull: ["$Publishers.reach", 0] } }
```